# How to use the given FFT function in C?

Tags: c, fft

Sorry this is the first time for me to ask question here, I've given a FFT function

```
void fft_1d(int n, float xr[256], float xi[256], int ntype)
{
  /* compute the FFT of a complex signal
     xr and xi are the real and imaginary parts respectively
     xr and xi contain the signal as input and the FT as output
     n is the number of points, it should be a power of 2
     ntype is set to 1 for forward transform and -1 for inverse transform
  */
```

And I have been told to extend this function to do the 2D (DFT) of the given image.

My problem is:

1. I can get every itensity value of the given image but how can I deal with the complex components (real part /imaginary part) of the fft_1d? In other words, what should I put in the parameters `float xr[256]` and `float xi[256]` in order to do the 2D (DFT) of the image?

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 3):

An image is, generally, a real-only function.  Therefore, you can set the real inputs to be the image values, and the imaginary inputs to zero when calling the FFT function.

However, in order to perform a 2D FFT, you must first call the 1D FFT on each row, and then call the 1D FFT on each *column* of the results.  These intermediate results will be complex, and must be passed as such to the second set of FFTs.

Comment: Thanks for the answers~ But how can I actually use this function? I need to store the values after the 1st 1DFFT (which will be complex), but it seems that the function does not give any return values.

Comment: @Nick Li: I imagine from the function description that the FFT is *in-place*, i.e. the same arrays will also end up holding the results.

Comment: Yes, i think the function is in-place. So what I need to do is to feed in the function with all the intensity values which is in the form of a 2d array a[m][n](first by each row, and then for each column) ?

Comment: And one more, the data type I make use to store the intensity value is a character array, but the function's signature tells me to feed in a float array, is that mean I need to cast the char array first?

Comment: @Nick: You will need to create a new array of floats, and use a loop to convert each element in turn.  You can't just cast the array on its way into the function.

Comment: What you mean is to loop through every single elements of the char array and to the casting for every single char value to float value?